# Edit Perl $PERL5LIB and @INC

Tags: perl

I'm using macOS and I just add:

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/tools/modules/PERL/:$PERL5LIB
```

And:

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/tools/modules/PERL/"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"
```

And when I do:

```
echo $PERL5LIB
```

Or:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", @INC;'
```

It appear two times, I just want to edith both files `$PERL5LIB` and `@INC` to eliminate both paths.

How could I do that?

Comment: What appears two times?

Comment: Do you use *both* those `export` lines? If so; why?!

Comment: Anyways, it's usually better to add directories to the search path using the [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma in your scripts.

Comment: @Shawn, Hell no! Only use `use lib` (in combination with `$RealBin` from `use FindBin qw( $RealBin );`) for modules bundled with scripts. `PERL5LIB` should be used otherwise (e.g. for `cpan`-installed modules). This eliminates hardcoding paths and editing scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/tools/modules/PERL/:$PERL5LIB
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/tools/modules/PERL/"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"
```

with just

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/tools/modules/PERL/"${PERL5LIB:+:$PERL5LIB}"
```

Notes:

- There's no real harm to having a directory in `@INC` twice. (Just a tiny performance penalty.)
- You should remove that trailing slash, but it's harmless.
- The language is named "Perl. It's not an acronym, so spelling it "PERL" is inappropriate. A better directory name would be `perl`.

Comment: thanks so much for all your advise, I just fix the problem in this way (just before to read your answer): export PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/usr/local/genetools/perl_modules it is any difference ??  thanks !!!

Comment: Three bugs with that: Your directory will be searched last when you want it searched first, it creates a bad value if PERL5LIB is previously empty, and it suffers from an injection bug if the existing value of PERL5LIB contains any shell metacharacters (like space).